# Openshift rails app open4 (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, openshift

I am getting the following error when trying to deploy to openshift online (small gear):

remote: /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require': cannot load such file -- open4 (LoadError)
   remote:  from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in`rescue in require'
   remote:  from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
   remote:  from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.30.5/lib/openshift-origin-node/utils/shell_exec.rb:19:in`'
   remote:  from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
   remote:  from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in`require'
   remote:  from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.30.5/lib/openshift-origin-node/model/frontend_proxy.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
   remote:  from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in`require'
   remote:  from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
   remote:  from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.30.5/lib/openshift-origin-node/model/application_container.rb:18:in`'
   remote:  from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
   remote:  from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in`rescue in require'
   remote:  from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
   remote:  from /usr/bin/gear:21:in`'
To ssh://5410444f5973ca809a000005@wikipin-nopressurelabs.rhcloud.com/~/git/wikipin.git/
 ! [remote rejected] openshift -> master (pre-receive hook declined)

I have already tried to:

rhc env set BUNDLE_WITHOUT=development -a wikipin

But without success. Any other idea?
what I do not understand is why if my app is on ruby 2.0 I see ruby193 in the errors.. I also suspect it is linked with active record 4.0 something but haven't been able to troubleshoot it.

Gemfile:

```
source 'http://mirror1.prod.rhcloud.com/mirror/ruby/'
#source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.1.4'
gem 'rails-api'
gem 'open4'   # I have added this to see if the error could be resolved..
gem 'spring', :group => :development
gem 'pg'
gem 'rgeo-activerecord',
    :git => 'https://github.com/nopressurelabs/rgeo-activerecord',
    :branch => 'master'
gem 'activerecord-postgis-adapter'

# Serializer for JSON
gem 'active_model_serializers'
```

rhc app show

```
  Domain:          nopressurelabs
  Created:         Sep 10  2:30 PM
  Gears:           1 (defaults to small)
  Git URL:         ssh://########################@wikipin-nopressurelabs.rhcloud.com/~/git/wikipin.git/
  Initial Git URL: git://github.com/hiromipaw/wikipin.git
  SSH:             ##############################@wikipin-nopressurelabs.rhcloud.com
  Deployment:      auto (on git push)

  ruby-2.0 (Ruby 2.0)
  -------------------
    Gears: Located with jenkins-client-1, postgresql-9.2

  jenkins-client-1 (Jenkins Client)
  ---------------------------------
    Gears:   Located with ruby-2.0, postgresql-9.2
    Job URL: https://jenkins-nopressurelabs.rhcloud.com/job/wikipin-build/

  postgresql-9.2 (PostgreSQL 9.2)
  -------------------------------
    Gears:          Located with ruby-2.0, jenkins-client-1
    Connection URL: postgresql://$OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_HOST:$OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_PORT
    Database Name:  wikipin
    Password:       ############
    Username:       ############
```

Comment: Can you post your Gemfile and the output of rhc app show <appname>, but be sure to remove any usernames or passwords etc, also, is this on openshift online? or an openshift origin install?

Comment: I have the feeling it is connected to this: https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/open4-error-after-a-failed-deployment

Comment: But could also be related to this: https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/openshift-ruby-and-activerecord-4

Comment: Also, I think the problem started when I did a gem install rails.. I think somehow bundle is confused on which ruby to use.. but I can be wrong...

Comment: I deleted the gear. Created a new gear. Same repository same gemfile. It is now working.